# Password and Confirm Password not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to the committee and I have problems with my code because I'm using TextInputLayout and I want my Password and Confirm Password must validate but whatever I do it still giving me problems to fix it.

Here is my activity_register.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".Register">


<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_RegPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_RegCfmPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_input_RegPassword"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Confirm Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="101dp"
    android:text="Register"
    android:onClick="Reg"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my `Register.java` because I have tried to use equals but it won't work because when I want to type `.getText` is just invalid

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextInputLayout textInputRegPassword;
private TextInputLayout textInputRegCfmPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    textInputRegPassword = findViewById(R.id.text_input_RegPassword);
    textInputRegCfmPassword = findViewById(R.id.text_input_RegCfmPassword);

}

private boolean RegisterPassword(){
    String userReg = textInputRegPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    if(userReg.isEmpty()){
        textInputRegPassword.setError("Enter Password");
        return false;
    } else {
        textInputRegPassword.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean RegisterCfmPassword(){
    String userReg = textInputRegCfmPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    if(userReg.isEmpty()){
        textInputRegCfmPassword.setError("Enter Password");
        return false;
    } else {
        textInputRegCfmPassword.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}


public void Reg(View v){
    if(!RegisterPassword() | !RegisterCfmPassword() ){
        return;
    }


   }
}
```

Edited: I want my Password and Confirm Password Validate that both of them are the same and when I press the button, it just crash

```
private boolean Verify(){

    if(CfmPassword.getText().toString().equals(Password.getText().toString())){
        return true;
    } else{
        textInputRegCfmPassword.setError("Password Do Not Match");
        return false;
    }
}

public void Reg(View v){
    if(!RegisterPassword() | !RegisterCfmPassword() | !Verify() ){
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to get the text from the edittext, not the layout

Comment: but how because I do not understand

Comment: Also describe error or problem you are facing

Comment: @parekhkruti26 Read the post I just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

Register Class code

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextInputLayout textInputRegPassword;
    private TextInputLayout textInputRegCfmPassword;
    private TextInputEditText inputRegCfmPassword;
    private TextInputEditText inputRegPassword;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        textInputRegPassword = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.text_input_RegPassword);
        textInputRegCfmPassword =(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_input_RegCfmPassword);
        inputRegCfmPassword =(TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.input_RegCfmPassword);
        inputRegPassword =(TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.input_RegPassword);
    }

    private boolean RegisterPassword(){
        String userReg = inputRegPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(userReg.isEmpty()){
            textInputRegPassword.setError("Enter Password");
            return false;
        } else {
            textInputRegPassword.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean RegisterCfmPassword(){
        String userReg = inputRegCfmPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(userReg.isEmpty()){
            textInputRegCfmPassword.setError("Enter Password");
            return false;
        } else {
            textInputRegCfmPassword.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean Verify(){

        if(inputRegPassword.getText().toString().equals(inputRegCfmPassword.getText().toString())){
            return true;
        } else{
            textInputRegCfmPassword.setError("Password Do Not Match");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Reg(View v){
        if(!RegisterPassword() || !RegisterCfmPassword() || !Verify() ){
            return;
        }
    }   
}
```

And xml code is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".Register">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_RegPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_RegPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_RegCfmPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_input_RegPassword"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_RegCfmPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Confirm Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="101dp"
        android:onClick="Reg"
        android:text="Register" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will be help you!

Comment: Thank you so much and I deeply appreciate your help :)

Comment: @LEGENDPREDATOR if you feel like it, please accept my answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

`TextInputLayout` is just a design layout. You should get user input from its child `TextInputEditText`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/text_input_RegPassword"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
app:errorEnabled="true"
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/text_input_edit_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

then in your activity define `TextInputEditText`:

```
TextInputEditText password = findViewById(R.id.text_input_edit_password);
```

and finally get user input:

```
password.getText().toString()
```

Comment: I want both of my Password and Confirm Password to be same when I press the button if not the password will not match with the other one